# jenkins Extended E-mail Notification: ${BUILD_URL} 's port is wrong

Tags: email, jenkins

I use the  Extended E-mail Notification to set the mail notification. The tomcat default port is 8080, but I change to 9080.

I visited jenkins with this URL: `http://*.*.*.14:9080/jenkins/configure`

Now I set Extended E-mail Notification default content. Here is the code:

```
build result (For xxx) - "${PROJECT_URL}ws"${PROJECT_URL} 
SVN Url "${BUILD_URL}${BUILD_URL}
```

When I see the mail, the url port is not 9080, but 8080.

```
http://*.*.*.*:8080/jenkins/job/FinanceSys/70/
```

Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 7):

Go to Manage Jenkins -> Configure System, locate the "Jenkins Location" section and make sure that the Jenkins URL is setup properly.  I believe that value is what the Extended Email Notification plugin uses, not the URL you are using to access Jenkins in the browser.

For example, you could access Jenkins with "localhost:8080", but the emails get generated with "my.company.com:8080" - because that's what the Jenkins URL is set to.